# Help: Unable to connect to 5G Wifi on raspberry pi 4 using ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

I used the same image of arm64 version downloaded on site:https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi .

Since the download link of pi3 and pi4 are the same, I downloaded one of them, flashed to 2 SD cards, and inserted into raspberry pi3B+ and raspberry pi4B (4Gb model)

I used the default netplan package to config my WLAN connection, the configuration file is located in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "XXXXX_5G":
                    password: "********"
```

I am using the same configuration on pi3 and pi4, but the WIFI on pi4 won't work, ip addr command shows the interface is down.

After I removed the "_5G" suffix on pi4 (which is the ssid of 2.4G wifi), and "netplan apply", it connected to the network successfully.

I don't know if this is an known driver issue or something like netplan issue?

I've tried swap the two SD card, the pi4 just won't connect to the 5G wifi AP.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Edit this file:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/crda
```

And add your country code (`US` for me)

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Changed it and rebooted, 5 GHz showed up immediately.

Comment: Right on the money for me as well.  Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS on a RPi 4 4GB.

Answer (score 3):

This same issue was driving me crazy the last two days, because I installed 19.10 on my Pi 4 with the 7” touchscreen, and wanted a desktop but didn’t want to do MATE or Lubuntu because their windows are hard-coded for > the touchscreen’s 800x480 resolution, making them impossible to use. So I did Enlightenment instead, which works wonderfully, but didn’t seem able to configure networks out of the box.

So I figured out an inelegant but working solution. The issue for me, and probably for you as well, is that 5ghz is a regulated frequency, which means if you don’t set your country code, you won’t be able to connect.

Here’s what I did, and I hope it works for you!

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt install network-manager wireless-tools`
- The key is to make NetworkManager know your country code. You can do this temporarily with the command `sudo iw reg set`[your country code, if you’re in America it’s `US`]
- `sudo nmtui` This opens nmtui, the shiny interface for NetworkManager. You should be able to see your 5ghz networks now!

But there’s a problem here: this won’t persist after reboot. You have to do it manually every time. I tried using rc.local and it didn’t work, so I used crontab and it worked perfectly. Just remember: *this has to be in the root user’s crontab* (in this case just the `ubuntu` user).

- `crontab -e` (It’ll ask you what editor, I like nano myself.)
- add this to the end of the file: `@reboot iw reg set`[your country code as before]

Save it and `sudo reboot now` and when you’re back up, run nmtui as before and you should see your 5ghz networks!

You can create a configuration in nmtui to auto-connect to a network, which I did, so my Pi 4 running 19.10 connects automatically to my home network, but you can always run nmtui from the command line to connect to something else.

I have no doubt there are a billion better ways to do this, but this was a fast and working solution for me. If it doesn’t for you, chime in and I’ll figure out if I did anything else, as I’m doing this from memory 8 hours later and slightly high.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it may be a power/distance shortfall (Higher frequencies, require higher powers). The answer (a bad one)... move your Pi closer to your router.

What I have not yet attempted, since it seems that it is actually... illegal (and I honestly can't wrap my brain around the 'why' of it being so, but that is the general consensus on another forum), is that you can mod your Pi, to host an external antenna:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZGMGs6RDtc

References to the whole power/distance threads:

https://forum.libreelec.tv/thread/20578-fresh-install-raspberry-pi-4-5ghz-wifi-not-working/

Not exactly sure what the rules are for posting external links.